# Alternative for cURL and file_get_contents

Tags: php, xml, curl

Is it possible to get data from another website if my free server has disabled both cURL and allow_url_fopen? I would like to use function similar to simplexml_load_file, but I don't know how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution - in WordPress you can use SimplePie class. The code that I need:

```
$simple_pie_object = new SimplePie_File($url);
return $simple_pie_object->body;
```